# PHP export to CSV & open in excel without having to use text import wizard

Tags: php, excel, csv

This is kind of silly and unecessary but also kind of a waste of time since I am doing this every day. But I am wondering if there is a way to export data using PHP to CSV that does not require the use of the text import wizard when opening the file in excel.

Currently my code looks like this which I think seems to be pretty standard every where I look:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename=exported_shipments_'.date("Ymd").'.csv');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo "name" . "\t";
echo "address_1" . "\t";
echo "address_2" . "\t";
echo "city" . "\t";
echo "province_code" . "\t";
echo "postal_code" . "\t";
echo "country_code" . "\t";
echo "phone" . "\t";
echo "package_contents" . "\t";
echo "description" . "\t";
echo "value" . "\t";
echo "value_currency" . "\t";
echo "order_store" . "\t";
echo "order_id" . "\t";
echo "package_type" . "\t";
echo "size_x" . "\t";
echo "size_y" . "\t";
echo "size_z" . "\t";
echo "size_unit" . "\t";
echo "weight" . "\t";
echo "weight_unit" . "\t";
echo "postage_type" . "\t";
echo "signature_requested" . "\t";
echo "insurance_requested" . "\t";
echo "ship_date" . "\t";
echo "\n";
```

And so on.

Is there anything I can do so that excel recognizes that I want it to be delimited right away instead of having to use the wizard?

Comment: if its a csv, why are you using tabs? what does the C in csv stand for?

Comment: Saving as excel xls/xlsx is not an option to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using tab, not comma to separate the CSV. You also can force the *Content-Type* to *application/vnd.ms-excel*, and set the extension to *.xls*, it'll open with Excel and automatically import CSV.

You can use this code to do this:

```
<?php
header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exported_shipments_" . date ( "Ymd") . ".xls");
header ( "Pragma: no-cache");
header ( "Expires: 0");

$data = array ();
$data[] = "name";
$data[] = "address_1";
$data[] = "address_2";
$data[] = "city";
$data[] = "province_code";
$data[] = "postal_code";
$data[] = "country_code";
$data[] = "phone";
$data[] = "package_contents";
$data[] = "description";
$data[] = "value";
$data[] = "value_currency";
$data[] = "order_store";
$data[] = "order_id";
$data[] = "package_type";
$data[] = "size_x";
$data[] = "size_y";
$data[] = "size_z";
$data[] = "size_unit";
$data[] = "weight";
$data[] = "weight_unit";
$data[] = "postage_type";
$data[] = "signature_requested";
$data[] = "insurance_requested";
$data[] = "ship_date";
$fp = fopen ( "php://output", "w");
fputcsv ( $fp, array_values ( $data), ",", "\"");
fclose ( $fp);
?>
```

Comment: I did not realize you can save as excel from PHP thanks so much

Comment: bad idea, excel will detect the file type does not match and issue a warning, just call a csv a csv .. tested locally, above got warning, proper csv headers worked fine

Comment: Note however that you will still encounter grief if you use extended characters - Excel is famous for its inability to properly import a UTF-8 csv file, and there is no single fix that works for all versions of Excel.

Comment: @IdontDownVote yes I got that error so I will just stick with fixing the csv using commas instead of tabs I suppoe

Comment: all you needed to do,